# How to build a dendrogram from a directory tree?

Tags: r, dendrogram

Given a root absolute directory path. How do I generate a dendrogram object of all path's below it so that I can visualize the directory tree with R?

Suppose the following call returned the following leaf nodes.

`list.files(path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE`)

```
root/a/some/file.R
root/a/another/file.R
root/a/another/cool/file.R
root/b/some/data.csv
root/b/more/data.csv
```

I'd like to make a plot in R like the output of the unix `tree` program:

```
root
├── a
│   ├── another
│   │   ├── cool
│   │   │   └── file.R
│   │   └── file.R
│   └── some
│       └── file.R
└── b
    ├── more
    │   └── data.csv
    └── some
        └── data.csv
```

It would be especially useful if the solution involved decomposing the file system tree into two `data.frame`'s:

1. a table of nodes (with which I could include attributes such as modification date)
2. and a table of edges (also with attributes)

And then building the dendrogram object from those two `data.frame`s.

Comment: Exactly what type of plot did you have in mind? Can you show an example of how you want the data formatted and how you will plot your dendrogram? Anything to help make the problem more [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: A simple hierarchical tree plot would be a great first step. But I am hoping to make a tree map as well.

Comment: And I'd like to color attributes such as modified date.

Comment: This is currently all so hypothetical. It would help if you could make it concrete. Is the problem reading the file system? Is the problem the plotting? If it's both it would be easier to break it into two parts (perhaps separate questions). Provide desired data or a sample reference plot.

Comment: Are you using R under Linux ?

Comment: I am using Linux.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a possible approach to get what you originally asked for which is a system like tree.  This will give a `data.tree` object that's pretty flexible and could be made to plot like you might want but it's not entirely clear to me what you want:

```
path <- c(
    "root/a/some/file.R", 
    "root/a/another/file.R", 
    "root/a/another/cool/file.R", 
    "root/b/some/data.csv", 
    "root/b/more/data.csv"
)


library(data.tree); library(plyr)

x <- lapply(strsplit(path, "/"), function(z) as.data.frame(t(z)))
x <- rbind.fill(x)
x$pathString <- apply(x, 1, function(x) paste(trimws(na.omit(x)), collapse="/"))
(mytree <- data.tree::as.Node(x))

1  root                  
2   ¦--a                 
3   ¦   ¦--some          
4   ¦   ¦   °--file.R    
5   ¦   °--another       
6   ¦       ¦--file.R    
7   ¦       °--cool      
8   ¦           °--file.R
9   °--b                 
10      ¦--some          
11      ¦   °--data.csv  
12      °--more          
13          °--data.csv  


plot(mytree)
```

You can get the parts you want (I think) but it'll require you to do the leg work and figure out conversion between data types in `data.tree`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#tree-conversion

I use this approach in my **pathr** package's `tree` function when `use.data.tree = TRUE` https://github.com/trinker/pathr#tree

**EDIT** Per@Luke's comment below...`data.tree::as.Node` takes a path directly:

```
(mytree <- data.tree::as.Node(data.frame(pathString = path)))

                levelName
1  root2                 
2   ¦--a                 
3   ¦   ¦--some          
4   ¦   ¦   °--file.R    
5   ¦   °--another       
6   ¦       ¦--file.R    
7   ¦       °--cool      
8   ¦           °--file.R
9   °--b                 
10      ¦--some          
11      ¦   °--data.csv  
12      °--more          
13          °--data.csv
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you could replace all of that code and keep just the created `path` variable at the top and `(mytree <- data.tree::as.Node(data.frame(pathString = path)))`. You don't need to use plyr or do any wrangling at all.

Comment: @Luke Excellent  I'll add this to the answer

Comment: `mytree` is supposed to be an environment, right? (class() still gives "Node" "R6") I'm asking, because plot(mytree) in RStudio opens a "Viewer" tab that I have never used and hardly ever noticed. Is there a way to have it plotted in a usual graphics device? The console output is truncated in my case -- that's why I ask.

Answer (score 25):

It's worth adding that excellent [**fs**](https://fs.r-lib.org/) package offers [**`dir_tree`**](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/dir_tree.html) function that delivers this functionality to R in a very convenient manner.

```
tmp_dir <- tempdir()
# Create some directories
for (i in 1:10) {
    dir.create(path = file.path(tmp_dir,
                                basename(tempfile(pattern = "dir")),
                                basename(tempfile(pattern = "sub_dir"))),
               recursive = TRUE)
}
# Create directory tree
fs::dir_tree(path = tmp_dir, recurse = TRUE)
```

## *Results*

```
/tmp/RtmpEhB0ne
├── dir15213121dd5903
│   └── sub_dir1521315a5425ba
├── dir152131227b086f
│   └── sub_dir1521314255d96b
├── dir152131353e6603
│   └── sub_dir1521315b52aeed
├── dir15213136870535
│   └── sub_dir15213127b34f64
├── dir1521313bbf738b
│   └── sub_dir152131473939ea
├── dir152131403f4fd5
│   └── sub_dir152131115296e7
├── dir152131503d0d55
│   └── sub_dir15213114368572
├── dir1521316f0bb0c3
│   └── sub_dir1521314aea266b
├── dir1521317fe305e9
│   └── sub_dir152131bcfe8a
└── dir1521319800dfb
    └── sub_dir15213129defd4a
```

---

In addition to printing directory tree, discovered paths can be returned to an object.

```
sink(file = tempfile(fileext = ".log"))
res_fs_tree <- fs::dir_tree(path = tmp_dir, recurse = TRUE)
sink()
res_fs_tree[[1]]
# [1] "/tmp/RtmpEhB0ne/dir15213121dd5903/sub_dir1521315a5425ba"
```

Comment: This is great---I was even using fs and couldn't find this because ```dir_tree``` doesn't seem like it's related to ```print```/viz.

Comment: saving to an R object was the real value to me.  It would be great if saving to an R object would be an optional parameter to the dir_tree function

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Windows, you can use my package `dir2json`, by installing it like this:

```
drat::addRepo("stlarepo")
install.packages("dir2json")
```

It is also possible to use it on Linux, but there is a DLL linked to the GHC dynamic libraries, which must be installed on the system (while this DLL is standalone on Windows).

```
> library(dir2json)
> cat(dir2tree("src"))
src
|
`- contrib
   |
   +- PACKAGES.gz
   |
   +- PACKAGES
   |
   +- jsonAccess_0.1.1.tar.gz
   |
   +- expansions_1.2.tar.gz
   |
   `- dir2json_2.1.0.tar.gz
> cat(dir2tree("src", vertical=TRUE))
                                            src                                             
                                             |                                              
                                          contrib                                           
                                             |                                              
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------           
     /          |                 |                       |                      \          
PACKAGES.gz  PACKAGES  jsonAccess_0.1.1.tar.gz  expansions_1.2.tar.gz  dir2json_2.1.0.tar.gz
```

The package also contains a Shiny application which generates an interactive Reingold-Tilford tree representation of a folder:

```
> dir2json::shinyDirTree(".")
```

[image: Reingold-Tilford folder]

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Laurent I am having trouble installing the dir2json package. This is the error I receive: ```Error: package or namespace load failed for 'dir2json':  
   .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users//Documents/R/win-library/3.6/dir2json'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dir2json’ had non-zero exit status```

Comment: It seems like R cannot open this URL, which does not exist for me: ```Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://stlarepo.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://stlarepo.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'```

Comment: @Jasppo Ah yes, it does not exist for R 3.6. Can you try `install.packages("dir2json", type = "source")`?