# How to I see visual of my folder structure in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

What is the code go visualize your folder structure in RStudio?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `paths` variable to be the vector of all the files within the directory and all the files within the subfolders of the directory:

```
paths = unique(c(list.dirs(full.names = T),list.files(full.names = T)))
```

Then, borrowing the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094183/how-to-build-a-dendrogram-from-a-directory-tree), we can visualise the structure as a tree:

```
library(data.tree); library(plyr)

x <- lapply(strsplit(paths, "/"), function(z) as.data.frame(t(z)))
x <- rbind.fill(x)
x$pathString <- apply(x, 1, function(x) paste(trimws(na.omit(x)), collapse="/"))
(mytree <- data.tree::as.Node(x))
```