# R: Visualizing Folder Paths

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

**I am trying to make a network/tree visualization that shows all the folders, subfolders and files that are located on my computer.**

I found the following code which can list all files/folders on my computer:

```
dirs <- list.dirs(path = ".", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
```

From here, I want to make a network diagram visualization (e.g. using igraph) to show all the paths to folders, subfolders and files:

[image]
https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/ajcb4n/i_made_a_graph_visualization_of_my_projects/

I found this post here that shows how to do this for a limited setting: [How to build a dendrogram from a directory tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094183/how-to-build-a-dendrogram-from-a-directory-tree)

But I am trying to directly do this for this statement

```
dirs <- list.dirs(path = ".", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
```

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

**My attempt:**

```
library(igraph)
library(data.tree)

dirs <- list.dirs(path = ".", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

edges <- data.frame(from = dirname(dirs), to = basename(dirs), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed=TRUE)

plot(g, layout=layout_as_tree)
```

Comment: To get a tree, you can use the **jsTreeR** package with **Shiny**.

Comment: these might be helpful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094183/how-to-build-a-dendrogram-from-a-directory-tree

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this using `tidygraph` and `ggraph`:

```r
library(igraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

do.call('rbind', 
  strsplit(dirs, '/') |>
  lapply(\(x) sapply(seq_along(x), \(y) paste(x[1:y], collapse = '/'))) |>
  lapply(\(x) cbind(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1)))
  ) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  unique() |>
  graph_from_data_frame() |>
  as_tbl_graph() %>%
  mutate(label = gsub('^.*/(.*)$', '\\1', name)) |>
  ggraph(layout = 'tree') + 
  geom_edge_diagonal(color = 'gray') +
  geom_node_point(shape = 21, fill = 'lightblue') +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = label), size = 3, nudge_x = 0.4) +
  coord_flip(clip = 'off') +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_graph()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I have a few pointers: First, your Tree does not generate correctly, because dirnames does not give the name of the directory, but the whole name.

You can fix this by leaving out the `basename` function in the definition of your `edges` data.frame. This might also help with duplicate folder names. You can still change the names with

```
V(g)$name <- basename(V(g)$name)
```

Second, if you want to have all files and directories your first line should probably be

```
filesAndDirs <- list.files(path = ".", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
```

And finally, when plotting you should probably add the root of your tree:

```
plot(g, layout=layout_as_tree(g, root = 1))
```

I can't really help on making a beautiful graph, but I hope this helps anyway.

The whole code is:

```
library(igraph)

filesAndDirs <- list.files(path = ".",
                           full.names = TRUE, 
                           recursive = TRUE, 
                           include.dirs = TRUE)

edges <- data.frame(from = dirname(filesAndDirs), to = filesAndDirs, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed=TRUE)
V(g)$name <- basename(V(g)$name)

plot(g, layout=layout_as_tree(g, root = 1))
```

Comment: @ backboned: thank you so much for your answer! Can you please write the full code from start to finish if you have time? thank you so much!

Comment: will this produce a multi layered graph? e.g. folder, sub folder, sub sub folder, etc?